# User logout by session in Django Rest Framework

Tags: angularjs, django, session, django-rest-framework

I have a application, where frontend written by Angular 6 and backend - by Django Rest Framework.

User logging out implemented on the frond with following code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-logout-modal',
  templateUrl: './logout-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logout-modal.component.scss']
})
export class LogoutModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<LogoutModalComponent>,
              private router: Router,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  logoutAndClose(): void {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.thisDialogRef.close();
    this.router.navigateByUrl(RouteUrls.Login);
  }
}
```

```
class ProfileSettingsViewset(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def logout(self, request):
        #???
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

That is, the user is not actually logging out.

How can I implement user logout by session on the DRF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to logout user you must implement a viewset.

if you use token base authentication simply delete token

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class Logout(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # simply delete the token to force a login
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

if you use session authentication backend you must logout user with Django backends like this:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class Logout(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # using Django logout
        logout(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

then in urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^logout/', Logout.as_view()),
]
```

in your angular component must call Ajax request to this view before deleting clearing local storage content

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I implement logout based on the `session`. Will the required `session_id` go automatically to the backend (to `DRF` view)? How to call ajax request in the `angular` to this `view`?

Comment: all cookies send to server by each request. you can call Ajax request with angular using HttpClient. see link `https://angular.io/guide/http`